Is Gamma function just an analytical continuation of factorial or is there more?
Factorials are the number of arrangements of things. Is there a similar interpretation for the Gamma function or is it just an extension of factorials? Does $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)!$ mean anything?? I looked up on YouTube and browsed for a while, but all I see is a derivation of gamma and its relation to factorials. Thanks in advance.

See for example this thread and "Is the Gamma function mis-defined?"

@RaymondManzoni I'm sorry but I'm asking if there's any geometrical interpretation or a physical meaning for gamma. Like how 3 factorial means numbers of way 3 items can be arranged .

There is a graphical interpretation and it’s related to the volume of an Nth ball https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball

There isn't a physical interpretation of the generalization. But that is common in Mathematics. For example, what is the interpretation of $x^{1/2}$? What do you mean by "Multiply $x$ by itself one-half times"? Does that also bothers you?

The Gamma function is not just an extension of factorials. Perhaps the answers to this quesiton on construction of the gamma function will help you to more fully appreciate it.
